# How to stress a word in a sentence? Speak louler and clearly or say higher in pitch?

Tags: word-stress, intonation

I can easily find out which word that is stressed in a sentence if it's **(1) both said clearly, loudly and said in the highest pitch range** of that sentence. **But** in some cases, the speaker just **(2) says quickly one word in the highest pitch, and says another one clearer, slightly slower and louder**. So if the the first case **(1)** is not mentioned, then...

> **Which one - (2) saying clearly, slightly slowly and loudly or saying quickly in the highest pitch range of a sentence - is a natural way to emphasize a word in a
>   sentence?**

---

To understand what I'm talking about the second case **(2)**, the below examples show you features of the second case **(2)**

i. [**THINK him in the BAND**](https://youtu.be/QVoleJYgdM8?t=275) ("think" is higher in pitcher than "band", but "band" is clearer and more powerful than "think". > If someone wants to say that both "think" and "band" are stressed, then **why does "band" only sound powerful but it's not in higher pitch than "think"?**)

ii. [**STARTED it off in ASIA**](https://youtu.be/m9Nkqm7FFgk?t=77) (Same problem and same question with the **iv**)

iii. [**don't even know**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqQAlZcIf4Y&feature=youtu.be&t=733) ("know" is drawled longer and sounds clearer than "don't even", but "don't ev..." is in higher pitches than "know"

iv. [**absolutely gorgeous**](https://youtu.be/_isSm8mf-44?t=1160) ("absolutely" is in higher pitch than "gorgeous", but it sounds less powerful than "gorgeous")

Comment: You seem to be talking about [***prosodic stress***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)#Prosodic_stress) - specifically, the "subclass" thereof described in that linked Wikipedia article as *used pragmatically to emphasize (focus attention on) particular words or the ideas associated with them* (which as they say there is *normally transcribed as italics in printed text or underlining in handwriting*). In English, such stress primarily involves syllables being ***longer and/or louder*** - pitch changes aren't normally even *present*, let alone required, noticed, or significant.

Comment: [Here's an interesting observation.](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/206fnj/whats_the_difference_between_stress_accent_and/) We tend to assume that if pitch changes at all in the context of a stressed term, higher stress (primarily, ***longer / louder***) might be reflected / amplified by ***higher pitch***. But as someone points out in that linked Reddit thread, *There are some interesting variations. In the Birmingham English accent, stress is indicated by a **drop in pitch** along with a longer, louder syllable.*